# create dataframe from json object not wrapped in a key with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, api

I am looking to write an API response do a pandas data frame using Python where the JSON object is **not** wrapped in a key

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'authorization_is_working',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
ip_list = ["1.2.3.4", "5.6.7.8"]
for ip in ip_list:
    response = requests.get(f'https://.../ip-owner/{ip}', headers=headers)
# data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Here is a sample of the JSON being returned.  I am looking to write this to a dataframe and append rows as the call goes through the ip_list

```
{'1.2.3.4': {'manager_name': 'joe_smith', 'manager_email': 'joe_smith@abc.com', 'region': 'XYZ', 'name': 'hello', 'hypervisor': 'world.abc.com', 'project_name': 'hello_world'}}
```

Comment: what did you try? how about `pandas.json_normalize()`? What result do you expect - how it shoold look in table? You can always write own code to do it. it should be simple.

Comment: I tried using something like the following, but it errors out on "KeyError: 'value'" because there is no key

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(data["value"], columns=['manager_name', 'manager_email', 'region', 'name', 'hypervisor',project_name'])

Comment: it would need to get `list(data.values())[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `pandas.Series`

```
s = pd.Series(data['1.2.3.4'], name='1.2.3.4')
```

and append it to existing `df` as new row

```
df.append(s)
```

Because `append()` is deprecated so you can use `concat()` for this

```
df = pd.concat([df, s.to_frame().T])
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'1.2.3.4': {'manager_name': 'joe_smith', 'manager_email': 'joe_smith@abc.com', 'region': 'XYZ', 'name': 'hello', 'hypervisor': 'world.abc.com', 'project_name': 'hello_world'}}

df = pd.DataFrame()

name = list(data.keys())[0]  # '1.2.3.4'
s = pd.Series(data[name], name=name)

#name, values = list(data.items())[0]
#s = pd.Series(values, name=name)

print('--- Series ---')
print(s)

#df = df.append(s)
df = pd.concat([df, s.to_frame().T])

print('--- DataFrame ---')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- Series ---

manager_name             joe_smith
manager_email    joe_smith@abc.com
region                         XYZ
name                         hello
hypervisor           world.abc.com
project_name           hello_world
Name: 1.2.3.4, dtype: object

--- DataFrame ---

        manager_name      manager_email  ...     hypervisor project_name
1.2.3.4    joe_smith  joe_smith@abc.com  ...  world.abc.com  hello_world

[1 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: In this example, you are hard coding "data =".  Would this work for multiple IP addresses in ip_list ?

Comment: ir doesn't matter that I hardcoded data. if all results have the same structure then it will work with any result. Besides, you didn't show full URL so I can't test it on all your results - so you have to do it on your own.

Comment: my mistake.  meant to accept.